# Simple Text file storage AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am very new to cloud storage and hence need help. I want to use AWS cloud for proof of concept. There is a simple text file (.txt) that I need to store on AWS cloud and then read that file using a mobile app.

My question is what AWS service I need for this simple task - no DB related operations or processing power etc - only use it as dumb storage! The text file will be created on a PC using say Notepad and then uploaded to AWS which then will be read via a mobile app.

Many thanks in advance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a simple object storage you should use [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

You can interact with it via a [rich set of APIs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html). You can also retrieve objects publicly if there is no need to hide the files for public access, or presign the URL to add further security permissions by this the [presign](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/presign.html) command.

You can also improve performance and latency for your users by taking advantage of applying AWS CDN solution in front of your S3 bucket, [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

Comment: Thanks Chris for the prompt reply :)!

Do you have to pay to say store and read a 1MB file using S3? I read some of the documentation that is pay per read, etc but all sounds more towards running queries etc. while I want to just upload the file and download it. 

Thanks!

Comment: The pricing is all available here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing. For storing files you pay `$0.005` per 1000 objects and to retrieve you would pay `$0.0004` per 1000 objects  plus `$0.09 per GB` after the first 10GB of inbound transfer. You will also pay `$0.023 per GB` per month for storing the files.

Comment: This is super helpful Chris, you are a star, thanks! 
Quick clarification - when you say "objects" what is it exactly referring to? For instance, in my case if I am going to use one "X.txt" file, is the file one object or each data element in the file an object?

Comment: The file is the object in that case :)

Comment: Fabulous, thank you :). As a starting point, for my current minimalist needs, I believe I can get on with "AWS Free Tier". Thank you so much for you help! 
As part of the AWS Free Tier, you can get started with Amazon S3 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive 5GB of Amazon S3 storage in the S3 Standard storage class; 20,000 GET Requests; 2,000 PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST Requests; and 15GB of Data Transfer Out each month for one year.

Comment: Yes the free tier will last your for your first year of that account being opened

Answer (score 0):

S3 is the service that you want to use. It supports many different programming languages. For example, here are the different use cases you can perform using the S3 Java SDK.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3

Other languages have similar examples.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, very useful examples:)!